# Web Service - pass parameters

Tags: java, web-services

I have a table in *DB*:

```
id | name | surname | street
```

For a *WebService* I want to call a *method* and pass *parameters* to it that wrote to the database.
However, it may be possible to simultaneously write a few lines such as:

```
1 | Jan | Nowak | Jasna

2 | Piotr | Kowalski | Ciemna
```

etc...

I need to pass as parameters name, surname, street. I thought about the transfer of maps, but when I passed two values ​​of `key-value` (name-surname), but here comes the third value. How best to do this?

Comment: By web service do you mean a generic web service or are you using SOAP?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you looking for a web services tutorial?  Maybe start here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html.

Answer (score 0):

The generally accepted way to do this for a generic web service is to do an HTTP POST whose body contains XML or JSON describing the values you want to insert.

For example you might POST to the resource `"/people"` somthing like the following:

```
<people>
  <person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Jan</name>
    <surname>Nowak</surname>
    <street>Jasna</street>
  </person>
  <person>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Piotr</name>
    <surname>Kowalski</surname>
    <street>Ciemna</street>
  </person>
</people>
```

Then in the code that handles the POST, you parse the XML (using JAXB or course) into Java objects then write these to your database via JDBC, Hibernate, MyBatis, etc.

It's important to use a POST here; passing too many parameters via GET is unreliable, and not the way HTTP was meant to be used.

Comment: But in your example I have value as hard coding?

Comment: Actually I said you pass a value _like_ the one in the answer.  The XML in the answer was just an example.